# Is there an analytic $\mathrm{P}$- ideal on $\omega$ which is not $\Sigma^0_2$ and not $\Pi^0_3$-complete?

Tags: set-theory, descriptive-set-theory

Soleski proved that for any analytic $\mathrm{P}$-ideal on $\omega$ is $\Pi^0_3$.
The usually example , such as   the density zero ideal $Z_0$ is $\Pi^0_3$-complete, $I_{\frac{1}{n}}$ is $\Sigma^0_2$-complete.
Is there  an example of analytic $\mathrm{P}$-ideal which is not $\Sigma^0_2$ and not $\Pi^0_3$-complete?